# Changing ActiveMQ Artemis persistence settings at runtime

Tags: activemq-artemis

I need ActiveMQ Artemis broker to be started in a zero persistence mode and then move to use persistence once the storage volume is available. Is there any smarter way of doing this than starting while referencing a `broker.xml` defining a zero persistence and then restarting while passing a path to the different `broker.xml` configuring persistence? I also see that touching `broker.xml` reloads configuration, but it's not clear to me if persistence can be managed this way without a hard restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *will* need to restart the broker if you want to move from a non-persistent configuration to a persistent configuration. The persistence configuration can't be changed at runtime.

See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/config-reload.html#configuration-reload) for more details on what is eligible to be changed in `broker.xml` at runtime.